# How to find the convex hull of a YUV image in C?

Tags: c, image-processing, yuv, convex-hull

Every code I have found in C that calculates the convex hull is based on giving it random points. If i have a YUV image and want to find the convex hull of the object in the image how can I do that?

Comment: "random points"? how about you start with segmenting/binarizing your picture first.

Comment: It seems like the first step would be to find the edges of your object in the image.

Comment: What's the significance of it being YUV, please? I don't see what difference it makes.